# Canvas doesn't get redrawn in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, macos, canvas, swiftui

I have a project in SwiftUI on macOS where I draw to a canvas twice per second.

This is my `ContentView`:

```swift
struct ContentView: view {
    @State var score: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Score: \(self.score)")
                .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: true)
            Canvas(renderer: { gc, size in
                start(
                    gc: &gc,
                    size: size
                    onPoint: { newScore in
                        self.score = newScore
                    }
                )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

The `start` function:

```swift
var renderer: Renderer
func start(
    gc: inout GraphicsContext,
    size: size,
    onPoint: @escaping (Int) -> ()
) {
    if renderer != nil {
        renderer!.set(gc: &gc)
    } else {
        renderer = Renderer(
            context: &gc,
            canvasSize: size,
            onPoint: onPoint
        )
        startGameLoop(renderer: renderer!)
    }

    renderer!.drawFrame()
}

var timer: Timer
func startGameLoop(renderer: Renderer) {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true, block: {
         renderer!.handleNextFrame()
     }
}
```

And the renderer roughly looks like this:

```swift
class Renderer {
    var gc: GraphicsContext
    var size: CGSize
    var cellSize: CGFloat
    let pointCallback: (Int) -> ()
    var player: (Int, Int) = (0,0)

    init(
        context: inout GraphicsContext,
        canvasSize: CGSize,
        onPoint: (Int) -> ()
    ) {
        self.gc = gc
        self.size = canvasSize
        self.pointCallback = onPoint
        self.cellSize = min(self.size.width, self.size.height)
    }
}

extension Renderer {
    func handleNextFrame() {
        self.player = (self.player.0 + 1, self.player.1 + 1)

        self.drawFrame
    }

    func drawFrame() {
        self.gc.fill(
            Path(
                x: CGFloat(self.player.0) * self.cellSize,
                y: CGFloat(self.player.1) * self.cellSize,
                width: self.cellSize,
                height: self.cellSize
            )
        )
    }
}
```

So the `handleNextFrame` method is called twice per second, which calls the `drawFrame` method, drawing the position of the `player` to the canvas.

However, there is nothing being drawn to the canvas.

Only the first frame is drawn, which comes from the `renderer!.drawFrame()` in `start`. When a point is scored, the canvas is also redrawn, because the `start` function gets called again.

The problem is that there is nothing being drawn to the Canvas when the `drawFrame` is called from `handleNextFrame`.

Where lies my problem, and how can I fix this issue?

Thanks in advance,
Jonas

Comment: Hey, by any chance, were you able to resolve this? If you did, do you mind sharing it as an answer? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Go to your project settings, select 'Build Settings' tab, and make sure 'Strict Concurrency Checking' is ON.
It will give you hints about GraphicsContext not being thread-safe, because it does not conform to Sendable protocol.

I am no expert on the topic, but I believe this means that GraphicsContext is not meant to be used in asynchronous context, you are not meant to save its reference for future use. You are given a GraphicsContext instance and you are meant to use it so long as the renderer closure's execution lasts (and this execution, of course, ends before your asynchronous callbacks could use the GraphicsContext instance).

What you really want is a TimelineView:

```
    import SwiftUI

private func nanosValue(for date: Date) -> Int { return Calendar.current.component(.nanosecond, from: date)
   }

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TimelineView(.periodic(from: Date(), by: 0.000001)) { timeContext in
            Canvas { context, size in
                let value = nanosValue(for: timeContext.date) % 2
                
                let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size).insetBy(dx: 25, dy: 25)

                           // Path
                           let path = Path(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: 35.0)

                           // Gradient
                let gradient = Gradient(colors: [.green, value == 1 ? .blue : .red])
                           let from = rect.origin
                           let to = CGPoint(x: rect.width + from.x, y: rect.height + from.y)
                           
                           // Stroke path
                           context.stroke(path, with: .color(.blue), lineWidth: 25)
                           
                           // Fill path
                           context.fill(path, with: .linearGradient(gradient,
                                                                    startPoint: from,
                                                                    endPoint: to))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

This will change the gradient colour of the drawn rectangle every nanosecond.
Funny thing, I have heard on some blog, you need a completely different mindset to use SwiftUI, haha. It just does not work the traditional way.